# How to change the color of a MSO_Connector - python-pptx

Tags: python-pptx

I have been using the MSO_Connector of pptx module to draw a line in the ppt via py script.

Following is my code to draw a line which works perfectly fine.

line1 = slides.shapes.add_connector(MSO_CONNECTOR.STRAIGHT, Inches(1), Inches(1), Inches(2), Inches(2))

By default the line color is Navy Blue. How do I change it to black?

I looked around but couldn't find any ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the .line.fill attribute of the connector you can change the colour etc.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_CONNECTOR
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
from pptx.util import Inches

prs = Presentation()

slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]

slide = prs.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)

line1 = slide.shapes.add_connector(MSO_CONNECTOR.STRAIGHT, Inches(1), Inches(1), Inches(2), Inches(2))
line1.line.fill.background()
line1.line.fill.solid()
line1.line.fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 0)

prs.save('test.pptx')
```